# How to reduce time to first byte (TTFB) of Django website

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm trying to reduce a webpage time to first byte (TTFB). The current TTFB is 1300ms. My goal is to reduce this to under 600ms.

The view requires 2 database accesses and a small loop with roughly 80 iterations.

I've optimized my code significantly. I don't think anything else can be done to the code. The 2 database calls are costing me about 0.4 seconds.

My current set-up:

Server: **EC2** t2.small (Linux)
Database: **RDS** db.t2.small

I'm thinking of upgrading my database to **db.t2.medium**. Any ideas on what upgrades I should make.

Here is the waterfall from [webpagestest.org](http://webpagestest.org)

[image]

Comment: Use caching and use cloud front to serve static content. Alternatively convert your django app to REST and front end in React where rendering and refresh is faster due to virtual dom, But that is a departure from MVC paradigm

Comment: I am using cloudfront to serve my static files. But that wouldn't even matter for TTFB.

Comment: A CDN like CloudFront will absolutely matter for TTFB for all the files served by the CDN. For the stuff not served by CloudFront, do you have any caching in place? You want to avoid database calls as much as possible. Cache things in Redis, use a reverse proxy like Nginx to cache entire HTTP responses. Enable HTTP/2. Maybe upgrade to a faster server. Spend some time profiling the application on the server side to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Try installing django debug toolbar and see if it sheds some light. The first step would be figuring out what is taking the time - db query, serialization, business logic, templates, etc. Can't optimize without knowing the root cause.

Comment: Just in-case anyones wondering what the solution was for me, it involved switching to jinja2 templates and changing the critical render path (moving non-critical css/js to the end or using the async or defer tags).

Comment: @Astar Did it really reduce the ttfb? How much did it decrease to?